# DocType xhtml1-transitional.dtd ignores table cell height

Tags: xhtml, html-table, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;">Header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 180px;">Links</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="height: 25px;">Footer</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet.css looks as follows:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Row 1 and 3 above have fixed heights. Row 3 is not filling the remaining space. If i omit the doctype, it works as expected. I need to use this doctype.

Comment: This isn't what you want to hear but this is not a valid use for tables - do you have the ability to change the markup? (and why can't you change the doctype?)

Comment: I'm not too sure what's wrong. Perhaps I do not understand your question well enough. 

I've tried out your code in both IE and Firefox and in both versions, the height attribute does indeed work. Perhaps you could clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify the browser you are trying to fix this in.

You should be using `<div>`'s anyway if you want to do things properly ;)

Comment: And whenever possible, he should be using more appropriate semantic elements instead of <div>s.

Answer (score 1):

That's a quirk of Almost Standards Mode triggered by `Transitional DOCTYPE`. Use `Strict DOCTYPE` instead.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko's_%22Almost_Standards%22_Mode
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to yell if you had the same problem I had. 
Try putting px after each declaration.
It did not work in either browser for me without that pixel designation.
I am finding this problem all over and a real headache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no web dev, but isn't height just applicable to block objects? Hence try setting the TR's height, and not the TD's.